# Inline without else in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to do this without else in dart `isUser == true && Text("hello")`  but this gives me an error while if I do that in react native it works any help

Comment: How you are comparing a text widget and a Boolean ?! can you specify what exactly u want ?

Answer (score 0):

You question is very obscure but if I understand you correct:

```dart
isUser ? Text("hello") : Text("you are not a user :<");
```

of

```dart
isUser ? Text("hello") : null;
```

Also give yourself some time to look at [language tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour).

Answer (score 0):

You can use like conditional if on widget

```dart
if (isUser) Text("hello")
```

Comment: Note that this answer is appropriate only within a collection literal.